# filtering an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have an aray of arrays (Objects) with id/nume:

```
Object { Biosecuritate=[Object {id=1,nume="bio"}, 
Object {id=5,nume="securitate"}], Deseuri=[Object {id=2,nume="des"}] , 
Reglementari=[Object {id=3,nume="Reglementari"}], 
Sol/Subsol=[Object {id=4,nume="Sol/Subsol"}] }

    var filtered = _.filter(domenii, function(item) {
            return (item[0].nume == "Reglementari" || item[0].nume == "Sol/Subsol")
    });
    console.log("filtered=",filtered);
    console.log("domenii=",domenii);
```

and I'm trying to "extract" only 2 objects from the 'matrix' but after I do the filter
it becomes:

```
[ [Object {id=3,nume="Reglementari"}], [Object {id=4,nume="Sol/Subsol"}] ]
```

How can I convert "filtered" to initial type, or to filter that without change it's "form"?

Comment: Wow @benjaminbenben, do **not** try to edit people's code like that. You completely invalidated the good parts of your edit.

Comment: "array of arrays (Objects)" - it's actually an Object with values of arrays of Objects

Comment: @meagar - it was pasted in from some kind of inspector.. I just changed the formatting so that you could play about with it

Comment: @benjaminbenben: If you want to suggest an improvement of the existing code, this is a valid answer a swell.

Comment: @DanielR it's not actually changing the code, just formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To maintain the object, you could reduce rather than filter:

```
var domenii = {
  Biosecuritate: [{id:1,nume:"bio"}, {id:5,nume:"securitate"}], 
  Deseuri: [{id:2,nume:"des"}] , 
  Reglementari: [{id:3,nume:"Reglementari"}], 
  "Sol/Subsol": [{id:4,nume:"Sol/Subsol"}]
}

var reduced = _.reduce(domenii, function(memo, item, key){
  if(item[0].nume == "Reglementari" || item[0].nume == "Sol/Subsol"){
    memo[key] = item;
  }
  return memo
}, {})

console.log("reduced=",reduced);
console.log("domenii=",domenii);
```

Comment: (I cannot vote for your answer - being useful because I don't have 15 rep.points)

Comment: @MihaiGodeanu an easy way to get rep is to accept answers that people give you by clicking the green checkmark next to your favorite answer

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to change the type of `domenii` to be a flat array but you could also just flatten the result.  Add this to the end:  `filtered = _.flatten(filtered);`